# How to check the check-boxes corresponding to API levels in Android SDK Manager?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio. I am following up a tutorial in the book - `The busy coder's guide to Android Development Version 7.3`,
The author pens down -

> The “SDK Platforms” tab lists the versions of Android that you can
>   compile against. The latest version of Android is usually installed
>   when you set up Android Studio initially. However, for the tutorials,
>   please also check “Android 4.4.2” and “Android 5.1.1” in the list, and
>   then click the “Apply” button to download and install those versions.

[image]

However, I see that the check-boxes corresponding to the `API levels` are `disabled` by default & I am unable to click them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest clicking that link at the bottom "Launch Standalone SDK Manager" and install packages from there instead of using the in-app manager in Android Studio. You should be able to install whatever you want from that screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning message says that you shouldn't have any spaces in the SDK path.  In your name in the path, there is a space. You could store the SDK somewhere else and try again.

Comment: It took me 2 to 3 hrs to download those components. If I change the location, it will download it once again, which is going to be annoying.

Comment: I don't think it will redownload. Just move them in the file system and edit your SDK location shown in your screen shot to the new location.